# continuous map on metric subspace.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Suppose f is a continous map from $(X,d)$ to $(Y,p)$. Suppose A is a subspace of $X$. Then the restriction of f from $A$ to Y is likewise continous.

My proof:

Let $a \in A$. Suppose $(a_n)$ is an arbitrary sequence contained in $A$ such that $a_n \rightarrow a$. Since $f$ is continous on X, $f(a_n) \rightarrow f(a)$.

Is this proof correct? How could I make it more detailed? What else should I include? Could you provide another proof?

Comment: Looks entirely correct. Other proofs would depend on your definition of continuity. Being a topologist, my definition of continuity is that "pre-images of open sets are open". In your context these two definitions are equivalent, so you could try proving that all pre-images of open sets are open?

Comment: @Matt, thanks so much for the reply. I will attempt to write a proof soon. However I have a question, is a metric space a topological space? We’re going to be learning about topological spaces in a few days, and I’m really curious.

Comment: A metric space is indeed (in the appropriate sense) a topological space, but not visa versa. The definitions of "metric" and "topological" spaces are quite different at first sight, but given a metric space, there is a natural "topological" space which it spits out - we say that the metric *determines a topology*. However, given a topological space, we do not necessarily have a way to spit out any sort of "natural" metric space. Alternatively said, metric spaces are very special sorts of topological spaces.

Comment: Recall that given a metric, you can figure out what sets are open and which are not? Well, a topological space is like a metric space except *all you're given is the open sets*. These might be sets which were determined to be open because they came from a metric, or they could have been simply chosen, not in a way that goes along with any metric. The choice of open sets for a topological space has to conform to a couple of rules, but those rules don't include one which says that there was once a metric which we've now forgotten about.

Comment: @Matt that’s so interesting. I really can’t wait to learn about topological spaces. Thank you so so so much!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll turn the above into an answer so that you can mark it as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of providing an answer rather than a comment:

Looks entirely correct. Other proofs would depend on your definition of continuity. Being a topologist, my definition of continuity is that "pre-images of open sets are open". In your context these two definitions are equivalent, so you could try proving that all pre-images of open sets are open?

A sketch of my alternative proof would be something like:

$f:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous, so for any open set $B \subseteq Y$, its preimage $f^{-1}(B)$ is open.

I now look at the open sets in the subspace $A \subseteq X$. There is possibly some lemma that would help me here.

I now deduce that if $f^{-1}(B)$ is open in $X$, then ${\widehat{f}}^{-1}(B)$ is open in $A$, where $\widehat{f}$ is the restriction of $f$ to $A$.

That should give you the bare bones.